# How to open printer in network share or how to enumerate list of network share printer?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, network-share, network-printers

How to open printer in network share or how to enumerate list of network share printer ?

I have tried OpenPrinter() API, but got error, and these my sample code

MF633C/635C --> It is printer name in network share.

```
BOOL value = OpenPrinter("MF633C/635C", &h, NULL);
if(value == 0)
    cout << "Not a printer" << endl;
else
    cout << "It is a printer" << endl;
```

How to open a network printer and how can I identify it is a printer or not.

I got the error as **The printer name is invalid**.

Error code is **2351**.

***How to pass the share network printer ?***

Is there any api?

Comment: what error? Please post a [mcve] and the error message

Comment: Like any other Windows API function, the [`OpenPrinter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/openprinter) functions sets an error code which can be retrieved with [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror). Use this to find out *why* the call failed.

Comment: have you tried using `R"(\\MF633C\635C)"`?

Comment: yes I have tried it shows **R is undefined**

Comment: [EnumPrinters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/enumprinters)

Comment: @ArunArun `R"(...)"` syntax was added in C++11. If you are using an older compiler/standard, you will have to escape the string instead, eg: `"\\\\MF633C\\635C"`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude a lot of Win32 APIs don't use `GetLastError()` to report error codes. Many return `HRESULT`s instead. And some don't even report error codes at all. So, refer to documentation on a function-by-function basis

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetenumresourcew

Comment: You need to *Settings->Bluetooth & devices->Printers & scanners->add device* or [AddPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/addprinter). Then you could *OpenPrinter*.