# How to display only network printers when enumerating FOLDERID_NetworkFolder?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, network-share

The code below shows all devices, from network devices like network share, media device, printers, etc.

```
hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("CoInitialize error, %x\n", hr);
    return;
}

hr = SHGetKnownFolderItem(FOLDERID_NetworkFolder, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShellItem));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("SHGetKnownFolderItem error, %x\n", hr);
    return;
}

hr = pShellItem->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_EnumItems, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShellEnum));                
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("BindToHandler error, %x\n", hr);
    return;
}

do {
    IShellItem* pItem;
    LPWSTR szName = NULL;
    SFGAOF attributes;

    hr = pShellEnum->Next(1, &pItem, nullptr);
    if (hr == S_OK && pItem)
    {
        hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, &szName);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && szName != NULL)
        {   
            wcout << szName << std::endl;
        }        
    }
} while (hr == S_OK);

CoUninitialize();

system("pause");
```

From this, how can I print only network printers?

Comment: Your previous question produced [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75446412/how-to-open-printer-in-network-share-or-how-to-enumerate-list-of-network-share-p#comment133134378_75446412), that links you to the respective APIs. Full sample code is here: [Enumerating Network Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/enumerating-network-resources).

Comment: @ArunArun On a side note: your code is leaking all of the COM interfaces and dynamic memory that you obtain. You need to `Release()` the interfaces, and free the `szName` memory, when you are done using them, before you call `CoUninitialize()`. You are also not calling `CoUninitialize()` before `returrn`'ing when an error occurs. In any case, as IInspectable indicates, this is the completely wrong API to use for your needs in the first place.  Use APIs that are more printer-oriented instead of Shell-oriented.